# GitKraken: Unable to commit files and merge branches

Tags: gitkraken

I am unable to commit files in GitKraken after staging as the "Commit" button just doesn't respond. Also, whenever I try to merge a branch (most cases  it's master) I get an error saying "Signature Author Required". Yet, I am able to do everything in the command line. I've attempted to reach out to Axosoft but since I'm using the free version it seems unlikely that I'll get any response. I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing the program but to no avail. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Gitkraken uses its own git library - so the version can be different to the git version you have installed on your system. Maybe thats why you have different behaviours. 

You can try and check your Profile-Settings in Gitkraken and fill up those fields (name, email).